# How to send an email in the background from an android application?

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have an requirement which needs to send an mail in the background without user intervention. I was using JavaMail API. But recently I started getting security alerts from Gmail  and the sign in attempts using this method were blocked. So is there any other method or service I can use to replace this?
Edit:1. I should add that less secure apps are allowed access the Gmail account used to send the mail.
2. I want to send the mail from an email Id I know the user name and password to and not the users email

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: I'll check this out but are you sure this method does not need any user interaction?

Comment: Do you want to send the email like it has been send by your app OR like it has been send by the user??

Comment: I want to send a mail like it's been sent by my app.

Comment: Then use Gsuite API in android.

Comment: @SATW I had the same requirement and issue with you, now I am using aws ses https://aws.amazon.com/ses/, please give it a try.